# Isolating the date a value turns 0 and aggregating another value from that date back

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm looking to see two things:

1. When a customer closed all of their accounts with us (date when
   accounts goes to 0)
2. The total interactions a customer had with us up
   until that point (sum of interactions from when accounts was a
   number greater than one).

The total interactions a customer had with us up
    until that point (sum of interactions from when accounts was a
    number greater than one).

Basically I'm trying to get from the top table to the bottom table in the attached image.

```
Customer    month   Accounts    Interactions
12345      Jan-15   3           5
12345      Feb-15   3           1
12345      Mar-15   2           7
12345      Apr-15   1           3
12345      May-15   1           9
12345      Jun-15   1           2
12345      Jul-15   0           3
67890      Feb-15   1           4
67890      Mar-15   1           4
67890      Apr-15   1           9
67890      May-15   0           5


Customer    Month close date    Interactions    
12345           Jul-15              30  
67890           May-15              23
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `month`?

Comment: It's in the date format. Specifically, it's the last day of the month since this is a monthly summary of the customer activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I first read the question it sounded like there would be a neat solution with window functions, but after re-reading it, I don't think that's necessary. Assuming that closing his last account would be the last interaction a customer would have with you, you just need the last interaction date per customer, which means this problem can be solved with simple aggregate functions:

```
SELECT   customer, MAX(month), SUM(interactions)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY customer
```

Comment: Thanks! That should do it and I'm surprised I didn't think about using the max function. What if I modified it to only sum interactions three months before closing? Also, I'm new to this so window functions sound interesting, I'll be sure to google and learn more about them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To get the last three months you need an OLAP-function:

```
SELECT Customer, MAX(months), SUM(Interactions)
FROM
 ( 
   SELECT Customer, month, Interactions
   FROM     mytable
   QUALIFY
   -- only closed accounts
       MIN(Accounts) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) = 0

   -- last three months
   AND month >= oADD_MONTHS(MAX(month) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer), -3)
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY customer
```